# Will tracking analytics with PHP produce false results VS google analytics?

Tags: php, mysqli, google-analytics, analytics

I have placed a query on my website header, basically the way it works is I have a mysqli query on each page pulling it's URL and does:

```
 INSERT INTO analytics (url) VALUES ($url);
```

Which just updates the table any time a page is loaded.

The problem is - I am seeing insane levels of traffic that are not anywhere even close to the levels reported by google analytics.IE: One page in google analytics is showing 1200 views - and in my table it's showing 4000. I expected a discrepency, but not this much.

Is there a reason for the discrepency? Is there any way to fix the tracking in my query to filter people out?

Comment: There are many 'robots', for instance from search engines, that also visit your site. On many sites there are more visits from robots than from real people, so you have to filter them out. Be aware, this is by no means easy. In other words: there's a reason Google dominates this market. You give them all your visitors data, you get something in return. Poor visitors are left in the cold.

Comment: Opening new tabs will add to that count, refreshing will add to that count, clicking back button to that page can add more count, even crawlers will add to that. This might be accurate to count how much the page is loaded, but not how much impressions it made.

Comment: @frz3993 I don't agree with you, pages might be cached and not reloaded from the server. Google uses Javascript and that will run every time a page is viewed. Trey could do this too, of course.

Comment: Well KIKO I'm just assuming the worst case scenario, php - dynamic - no cache. Of course Trey can do it too. Perhaps by taking into account some factors and the user behavior.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google analytics can also show incorrect data if you have not added a filter to remove data that is not coming from your page. If I visit your page I can copy your UA number and use it on my page. There are robots doing that to create spam in your Google analytics data.

Comment: If you add a field where you store the http headers you can use that to filter out bots, reloads etc (harder than it sounds, but doable, especially if you separate the processing from the data collection).

Comment: Have you also look at your server log? for the URLs; curious which number is closer.